# How to show uploaded image in admin

Tags: magento2, admin, media-images

I want to show uploaded image in admin form. I use this code to upload image in admin form.

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'image',
    'image',
    [
        'name' => 'image',
        'label' => __('Image'),
        'title' => __('Image'),
        'required' => false,
        'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
    ]
);
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 0):

Add addType() in admin form

```
 $fieldset->addType(
        'image',
        '\Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Flip\Renderer\Image'
        );
```

Now create renderer block(Image.php) at

`Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Flip\Renderer`

Copy this code

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Flip\Renderer;

class Image extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Image
{
    protected function _getUrl()
    {   
        $url = 'book'.$this->getValue(); // book is image directory
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Now you can see image on admin form.

Answer (score 0):

**First add this code into your Form Block File**

***Form.php***

> ```
>   $fieldset->addField(
>           'image',
>           'image', 
>               array(
>                       'label'     => 'Image',
>                       'required'  => false,
>                       'name'      => 'img',  
>                       'note' => 'Allow image type: jpg, jpeg, png',      
>                       )
>       );
> ```

**Now Change your Form Save Controller File to Save your Image File.**

***Save.php***

> ```
>       <?php
>
>       namespace [vendorname]\[modulename]\Controller\Adminhtml\locator;
>
>       use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
>       use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
>       use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
>       use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
>       use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
>       use Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory;
>
>
>       class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
>       {
>           protected $fileSystem;
>
>           protected $uploaderFactory;
>
>           protected $request;
>
>           protected $adapterFactory;
>
>           public function __construct(
>               \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
>               \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
>               \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
>               \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
>               AdapterFactory $adapterFactory
>
>           ) {
>               parent::__construct($context);
>               $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
>               $this->request = $request;
>               $this->adapterFactory = $adapterFactory;
>               $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
>           }
>
>           public function execute()
>           { 
>             $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
>
>
>             if (isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != '') 
>             {
>
>                try 
>                  {    
>
>                    $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);
>                    $uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
>                    $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
>                    $uploaderFactory->addValidateCallback('custom_image_upload',$imageAdapter,'validateUploadFile');
>                    $uploaderFactory->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
>                    $uploaderFactory->setFilesDispersion(true);
>
>                    $mediaDirectory = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
>                    $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('[Folder Name]');
>
>                    $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);
>
>                    if (!$result) 
>                          {
>                            throw new LocalizedException
>                            (
>                               __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath)
>                            );
>
>                          }
>
>                    $imagePath = '[Folder Name]'.$result['file'];
>
>                   // store image path in database table 
>
>                    $data['image'] = $imagePath;
>
>
>                  } 
>                  catch (\Exception $e) 
>                 {   
>                      $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
>
>                 }
>
>             } 
>
>             else if (isset($data['id'])) 
>             {
>               if((isset($data['image']['delete']) && $data['image']['delete'] == 1))
>               {
>                   // for image delete 
>
>                 $data['image'] = null;
>                 $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Image Deleted'));
>               }
>
>             } 
>
>             else
>             {     
>                   $this->messageManager->addError(__("Image not Save")); 
>                   $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
>                   return;
>             }
>
>
>          /* for save data */
>
>             try {
>                     $rowData = $this->_objectManager->create('[vendor name]\[modulename]\Model\locator');
>                     $rowData->setData($data);
>
>                     if (isset($data['id'])) 
>                     {
>                         $rowData->setId($data['id']);
>                         $rowData->setlocatorImage($data['image']);
>                     }
>                     $rowData->save();
>
>                     $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Information has been successfully saved.'));
>                   } 
>               catch (\Exception $e) 
>                   {
>                       $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
>                   }
>
>           $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
>
>         }
>
>       }
> ```

**Make a sure your image field in the table field must be 'nullable'=> true because image delete make this field's null. if it is not null then image delete operation not work because not null fields must have a value.**

***InstallSchema.php***

> ```
>   ->addColumn(
>               'image',
>               \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
>               255,
>               ['nullable' => false],
>               'Image'
>           )
> ```

**I Hope This Helps You.**